# run 2 instructions sequentially and execute the second instruction based on a condition in Python Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, boto3, boto

I have a requirement to execute 2 tasks sequentially in a Lambda Function in Python.
But as the execution is asynchronous I have to check the status of the first task regularly and run the second task only after the first task has the status AVAILABLE. I did not manage to do that with the code below. The second task starts at the latest line (create_access_key). I found this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/synchronous-waiting.html but I don't want to use a second Lambda function to execute the second simple task.

```
if e.response["Error"]["Code"] == "NoSuchEntity":
    client_sc = boto3.client('servicecatalog')
    create_user = client_sc.provision_product(
    ProductId='prod-9g59999d2djkg',
    ProvisionedProductName='Create_User',
    ProvisioningArtifactName='v1.1.002',
    ProvisioningParameters=[
        {
            'Key':'iamUserName',
            'Value':useriam
        },
    ]
)
get_status = client_sc.describe_provisioned_product(Id=pp_id)
status = status['ProvisionedProductDetail']['Status']
print (status)
while describe_status != 'AVAILABLE':
    time.sleep(20)
    if describe_status == 'AVAILABLE':
        create_access_key = client_iam.create_access_key(UserName=useriam) #second task
```

Comment: This is only a part of my lambda code, written in python with boto3

Answer (score 0):

Before the AWS CLI added `wait` commands to various services, what you are doing is almost exactly the same pattern that people used in bash scripts trying to create a sequence of CLI invocations.  Primitive polling.

There are `waiters` in Boto3 as documented at

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/clients.html

and

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/servicecatalog.html#ServiceCatalog.Client.get_waiter

but the ServiceCatalog client doesn't have any ready-made ones:

```
import boto3
# boto3.__version__ = '1.24.43'
sc = boto3.client('servicecatalog')
sc.waiter_names
[]
```

So rolling your own (as you do in your example code) may be the best option.

I know you don't want to add a second lambda function, but perhaps Step Functions are a useful alternative?

Does this lambda get invoked by someone clicking on a button in a web ui, hence the need to return a finished result?  If not, maybe treating this as a series of events and messages could be a possibility?

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your answer. Indeed servicecatalog method does not have any waiter in boto3. Do you know if I can use a simple while statement to do this ? I tried many different ways but no success yet.